# Infinite scroll on mobile and pagination on desktop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, infinite-scroll

i want to set infinite scroll plugin on my wordpress theme. This is the domain "http://www.unionsnetworksindacale.eu/". The plugin asks four items: https://s.w.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/screenshot-1.png?r=1204131. I'm not able to find the selectors. Then i want apply the infinite scroll only on mobile version. HELP!!!! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using "Forceful" WordPress theme from "Copa Themes" and you are using [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/) plugin.

As far I saw, you didn't modify any element classes. So your classes names for the configuration page will be:

Content Selector Class Name: **main-content**

Navigation Selector Class Name: **main-nav**

Next Selector Class Name: **next page-numbers**

Item Selector Class Name: **entry-content**

I took the class names from the official Demo site of this theme and matched with your theme. So these should work perfectly.

So far, this plugin doesn't support "only mobile" mood. So if you are desperate, you can hack it (but I won't suggest it anyway as it will break when then plugin updates and you will have to hack it everytime you update your theme/plugin).

So you can do it with javascript. At first, edit the plugin and remove the "wp_enqueue_script" function from the plugin so that it doesn't load the js file when the page loads. Then you can use the following condition to check the browser width and load the js manually on demand:

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width < 360) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin_js_location"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Which is not a good idea at all IMO.

A better approach will be using wp_is_mobile() function while enqueuing your plugin js. You can replace line 80 in plugin with the following code (I used version 2.6.2 for this code):

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'enqueue_js' ) );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions! Unfortunally the plug in doesn't work with these classes. Now i'm trying with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-infinite-scrolling/ any suggestion about this one?? :)

Comment: This seems to be a better one but this one doesn't have "mobile-only" feature either. Try and see if it serves your purpose or not.